# How might I include the output of another ActionController's view in my current controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to determine how to keep my controller DRY, and I have what might be considered a sub view (or control in other platforms) that will be included in many places in the app.

Is there a typical RoR DRY approach to handling this?

An example, if it helps, might be a "rate this page" type control/view. It will be included in different types of page controllers, and it doesn't strike me as an "extension" of the given page controller. Another suitable example may be a "contact us" form that would be available without a "dedicated" view.

Here is another similar question without an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408016/initializing-object-for-modal-form

The only comment admits that their proposed solution breaks standard design practices.

**Further details:**

An element of a view (some might consider it a control) that requires access to session data (to load user specific data, or to ensure that the user is only allowed to action once per session, etc.), access to validation information (for error handling on post), and may be included in may different views.

The issue that I'm currently trying to "fix" is that of "DRY"ing up the code in the cases that the element is included in views that already have view specific logic and output.

So let's consider the contact form element as an example. I want the ability for the client to submit a message at the bottom of most pages (different controllers make up the site obviously). One of the controllers happens to be a news page with some database output (articles). So this one controller is already designed to look after news articles and its views. Why would I put an initialiser in that controller for contact form? If the user tries to post an invalid form, who gets the error? I think the error should be inline, so now the news articles have to be re-populated as well as the contact form needs to appropriately alert the user.

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :collect_for_output


  def collect_for_output
    # some kind of business logic for grabbing the correct articles for
    # page we're on
    @articles= Article.all
  end

  def index
    # this initialisation doesn't belong in this controller
    # it should be in its own controller
    # I'm talking about initialisation that is dependent on session data
    # Say for a supplied name field I might pre-populate it with the
    # current users's name, otherwise allow it to be sent anonymously
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def post_message
    # this does *not* belong here but how else do I handle validation
    # in the current view?!? also how do I determine which view in this
    # controller made the post
  end
end


class NotAPageController < ApplicationController
  # this controller is nothing like a PageController, but I might
  # want the contact view available in these views too... how do I handle
  # the initialisation? (in these cases I'm talking about common
  # initialisation)
end
```

I am considering that my approach is all wrong, would be happy to be educated. I'd like to reiterate "rendering a partial with model that is only default initialised" is not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, what you need is a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Following your example you can create a partial template called `_contact_form.html.erb` in views/shared. So, you can add the the "contact us" form in several views in your application. To keep it DRY, create a new controller `contact_controller.rb` with a create action to handle the information sent in your form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the ContactController has no first-chance initialization before it gets rendered in the containing view? A typical pragmatic idiom I've seen in many of the tutorials is `form_for @some_obj` -- which wouldn't be initialized.

Comment: You can initialize the object in the controller action of each view in which you are using the form. But also you can create a form_for :contact, url: contact_path...

Comment: So I'd have to repeat logic between views?

Comment: Not in your views but in controllers. You have to initialize the @some_obj. In this case is better to use the symbol :contact. Take a look to form_for in http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Initialisze @some_obj -- once in special_page controller, again in employees_only controller, etc.? So then when I want to change/extend the init logic.... ?!?

Comment: THe logic is changed/extended in `contact_controller.rb`. In other controllers you only have to initialize `@some_obj = SomeObj.new`. As I said review `form_for` documentation and use `:contact` instead.

Comment: @cortext the form_for documentation that you keep referencing that `a form can be created by passing form_for a string or symbol representing the object we are concerned with:` has nothing to do with initialising the object in a DRY sense from the controller space. For example, using session data. I'm probably still misunderstanding what you meant. I will update my question to provide more details.